# Netbeans Maven & Web project

Tags: java, rest, maven, web, netbeans

This is the Snapshot of my REST service project structure on Netbeans

[image]

I have another running Maven project on Netbeans & Running(shown above) Web project on Netbeans(REST service deployed on Tomcat).

How can I integrate maven project into Web project or otherwise, so that When my REST service is called maven project starts running as well.